# how to write customizes css to get single webelement out of multiple matched webelements

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I have a `cssSelector` which is `div.formErrorContent` but with this there are 4 matched elements out of 4 I need to locate 1st element.
Can any one help me ?

I know how to write `xpath` for the same as :

```
(//div[@class='formErrorContent'])[1]
```

But I want `css` locator.

Comment: You need to show us the html, and the code for what you've tried already, please.

Answer (score 1):

without any html structure provided by you, i made 2 simple examples.

**A.** selecting with `:first-child` selector or `:nth-child` works only if the 4 divs with same class are all children of the same container, and are the only ones inside that container

see code snippet below

```css
#wrapper {
  background:blue
}
.formErrorContent{
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
}
.formErrorContent:first-child {
  background:green;
}
.formErrorContent:nth-child(2) {
  background:yellow;
}
.formErrorContent:nth-child(3) {
  background:white;
}
.formErrorContent:last-child {
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
</div>
```

**B.** or if you have more elements in that container, you can select the first div with that class depending on what element you have before it ( CSS = cascading style sheet so you can select only from top to bottom of the HTML structure, not the other way )

for example if you have a `p` element before `.formErrorContent` you should use the sibling connector `+` like so

```
p + .formErrorContent { background:green }
```

see snippet below :

```css
#wrapper {
  background:blue
}
p { 
color:white
}

.formErrorContent{
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
}
p + .formErrorContent { 
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<p>
This is a p element sibling of the other divs in this container
</p>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
<div class="formErrorContent">

</div>
</div>
```

what i want to point out is that there are a **number of ways** to achieve what you want, but it depends on the **html structure**